# Unexpected SELECT output from SQLite

Tags: php, sql, sqlite, select

5 mins ago was testing a query against SQLite database and got the following issue with `<` operator. Here's the info:

[Table schema]

```
CREATE TABLE products (
    name      TEXT,
    number    TEXT,
    category  TEXT,
    quantity  TEXT,
    available TEXT,
    price     TEXT,
    info      TEXT,
    prodlinks TEXT,
    pictures  BLOB
);
```

There are 100 items saved in the database in which I'm searching for specific based on the `quantity` value:

```
SELECT * FROM products WHERE quantity < 2;
```

This query is used in php script (part of it):

```
$result = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM products WHERE quantity < 2");
$result->execute();
$result = $result->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

The result is that all items that have `quantity` below 2 are returned, but there are returned items with `quantity` values above 2 - for example 11 or 15. Never saw that before, so do you have some idea where is the problem? If the `<` operator is reversed with `>` the items with 11 or 15 qty are not returned.

Comment: quantity is affinited to a string - you should cast it first.

Comment: Why is quantity a text? For strings there is '15' < '2' because text is compared character by character and '1' < '2'. Change your column data types so they represent the content.

Comment: In general as others already mentioned, your schema is completely wrong. You will have more problems querying any data from it. There is a reason why databases offer variety of data types.

Comment: Also as follows from above comments, you could have price in cents as an integer, as opposed to a dollar amount in float or text.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I'm not a database guy, written by someone who left a half-working system

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `quantity` column is defined as `text`, so the `<` operator will be interpreted lexicographically. If you can, you should probably redefine it as an `integer`. If this is not possible, you'll need to cast it when you query it:

```sql
SELECT * FROM products WHERE CAST(quantity AS INTEGER) < 2
```

Comment: Ok, this works, but which is better - to cast or to redefine the column?

Comment: @1000Gbps Definitely redefine the column if you can. `quantity` is a numeric value, and should be saved as such.

Comment: 1000Gbps: To redefine the column. Always use the appropriate data type. Otherwise you'll have to write such workarounds in every query or may get unexpected side effects here and there.

Comment: Seems redefining the `price` column with `REAL` cuts out the price decimal values, ie after the conversion values like `5.60` became `5.6`